# Mostrar linha de código de acordo com a data

Tags: php, data

Tenho uma página estática **que vai trabalhar offline** com a proposta de ser um painel de controles que terá a "programação do dia" de uma igreja. 
Em uma das colunas (como mostra na imagem) um dos vídeos será alterado diariamente e todo restante permanecerá intacto. A pergunta é: existe a possibilidade de deixar todas as tags  dos videos que usarei já listadas (porém ocultas) e mostrar apenas o video que preciso para aquele dia, predefinido por um comando que leva em consideração a data?

Linha de código atual:

```html
<video class="borda-player" src="videos/1.mp4" controls="true"></video>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vais ter videos para todos os dias? Como estão armazenados os videos/tags? Vêm de uma base de dados? Devias colocar o código relevante acerca dos videos/tags, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/265301/edit

Comment: Boa tarde Miguel! Vai ser um vídeo diferente para cada sábado do mês. essa é a linha que estou usando: <video class="borda-player" src="videos/1.mp4" controls="true"></video>

Comment: Seria qualquer coisa como isto: https://ideone.com/Do6ehs . em que as chaves do array serão os dias dos sábados do mês? podes testar colocando 26 como uma das chaves do array que é o dia de hoje

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde Talles,

Dá para fazer de 2 maneiras:

No próprio código você coloca uma clausula IF com o Now() para verificar a data e apresentar o vídeo que que.

Ou então fazer um banco de dados para e no banco de dados (pode ser um mysql simples) e cadastrar qual o caminho do vídeo que você quer para aquele dia.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Boa tarde Rodrigo! obrigado pela ajuda! Poderia me dar uma luz? Isso vai além do conhecimento básico que ainda tenho.rs Minha linha de código está bem simples. Veja: <video class="borda-player" src="videos/1.mp4" controls="true"></video>

Comment: if(strtotime('2017-12-25') == now())
{
echo(<video class="borda-player" src="videos/FelizNatal.mp4" controls="true"></video>);
}
elseif(strtotime('2017-12-31') == now())
{
echo(<video class="borda-player" src="videos/FelizAnoNovo.mp4" controls="true"></video>);
}
else
{
echo(<video class="borda-player" src="videos/DiasNormais.mp4" controls="true"></video>);
}


Mais ou menos isso ai